# Sorting array on two conditions

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

Ok, so I am having trouble coming up with a solution to my problem. Basically, what I am trying to accomplish is to total the number of registrations in the last twelve months, starting with the current month.

First, since I cannot guarantee  that each month would have a return, I built an array and populated it with my query results. I was able to pull all the data that I needed, but I am having trouble "sorting" them as you will.

I want to be able to display it in this manner, ex:

It is currently october so the months would list like this:

Nov 2014, Dec 2014, Jan 2015, Feb 2015, March 2015, ... October 2015.

Using this array

```
$months = array(
            '1'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>NULL), 
            '2'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>NULL), 
            '3'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>NULL), 
            '4'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>NULL),  
            '5'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>NULL),  
            '6'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>NULL),  
            '7'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>NULL),  
            '8'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>NULL),  
            '9'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>NULL),  
            '10'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>NULL),  
            '11'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>NULL),  
            '12'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>NULL)
        );
```

And populating it with the results I get:

```
key: 1 (January) total: 17 year: 2015
key: 2 (February) total: 20 year: 2015
key: 3 (March) total: 23 year: 2015
key: 4 (April) total: 29 year: 2015
key: 5 (May) total: 26 year: 2015
key: 6 (June) total: 26 year: 2015
key: 7 (July) total: 26 year: 2015
key: 8 (August) total: 24 year: 2015
key: 9 (September) total: 22 year: 2015
key: 10 (October) total: 24 year: 2015
key: 11 (November) total: 30 year: 2014
key: 12 (December) total: 42 year: 2014
```

Here's the query/loop

```
    $query = "SELECT MONTH(DATE_ADDED) as MONTH_NUMBER, MONTHNAME(DATE_ADDED) as MONTH_NAME, COUNT(*) as TOTAL_REGISTRATIONS, YEAR(DATE_ADDED) AS YEAR FROM MEMBERS WHERE DATE_ADDED >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL (DAY(CURDATE()) - 1) DAY) - INTERVAL 11 MONTH GROUP BY MONTH(DATE_ADDED) ORDER BY DATE_ADDED ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $months[$row['MONTH_NUMBER']]['NAME'] = $row['MONTH_NAME'];
    $months[$row['MONTH_NUMBER']]['TOTAL'] = $row['TOTAL_REGISTRATIONS'];
    $months[$row['MONTH_NUMBER']]['YEAR'] = $row['YEAR'];
    $months[$row['MONTH_NUMBER']]['MONTH_NUM'] = $row['MONTH_NUMBER'];

}

    foreach($months as $key=>$data){
        echo 'key: '.$key. ' ('.$data['NAME'].')   total:   '.$data['TOTAL'].'      year: '.$data['YEAR'].'<br/>';
    }
    exit;
```

Edit: So far, I've been able to accomplish this:

```
key: 12 (December) total: 42 year: 2014
key: 11 (November) total: 30 year: 2014
key: 10 (October) total: 24 year: 2015
key: 9 (September) total: 22 year: 2015
key: 8 (August) total: 24 year: 2015
key: 7 (July) total: 26 year: 2015
key: 6 (June) total: 26 year: 2015
key: 5 (May) total: 26 year: 2015
key: 4 (April) total: 29 year: 2015
key: 3 (March) total: 23 year: 2015
key: 2 (February) total: 20 year: 2015
key: 1 (January) total: 17 year: 2015
```

using this code:

```
function sortArray(array $a, array $b) {

    if($a['YEAR'] <= $b['YEAR'] && $a['MONTH_NUM'] < $b['MONTH_NUM']){
        return 1;
    }elseif($a['YEAR'] <= $b['YEAR'] && $a['MONTH_NUM'] > $b['MONTH_NUM']){
        return -1;
    }elseif($a['YEAR'] >= $b['YEAR'] && $a['MONTH_NUM'] > $b['MONTH_NUM']){
        return -1;
    }elseif($a['YEAR'] >= $b['YEAR'] && $a['MONTH_NUM'] < $b['MONTH_NUM']){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}
// Sort
uasort($months, 'sortArray');
```

Edit: You can see it sorts by the year properly, but lists the months the wrong way.

Edit: Desired Output

```
key: 11 (November) total: 00 year: 2014
key: 12 (December) total: 00 year: 2014
key: 1 (January) total: 00 year: 2015
key: 2 (February) total: 00 year: 2015
key: 3 (March) total: 00 year: 2015
key: 4 (April) total: 00 year: 2015
key: 5 (May) total: 00 year: 2015
key: 6 (June) total: 00 year: 2015
key: 7 (July) total: 00 year: 2015
key: 8 (August) total: 00 year: 2015
key: 9 (September) total: 00 year: 2015
key: 10 (October) total: 00 year: 2015
```

---

Ultimately, I will be displaying these in a bar graph showing the total per month over the last year.

I don't know if this is the best way to go about doing this, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Do you know about [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)?

Comment: (*and don't use `mysql_` functions, they're deprecated, change it to `mysqli_` functions or `PDO` objects*)

Comment: I was actually on php.net usort, I'll check into uasort. And Alan, using mysql is out of my control. That's how they have it set up (however I think they are looking to overhaul it in the near future) Thanks though

Comment: usort and uasort are alike, only that the second keeps index association, if any. Didn't it resolve your problem?

Comment: I've never used it, I am looking into how it works now. I did throw the example on my data to see the output, but I need to understand it further so I can write the comparison function

Comment: usort/uasort will sort your array inside itself and return you true upon success, or false on failure. Each element will be ordered by the return of your callback function, which leaves you free to impose any rule you want to the sorting. The callback gets two params, being `$a` one array element and `$b` the next array element to compare with `$a`. The comparison method is up to you. Returning a negative number, the element `$a` will descend. A positive one, it will ascend. If zero, it will keep its position.

Comment: How do I get it to sort on multiple columns? I got it to sort by year, but if I then sort it on the month it's going to change the order of the years

Comment: Try nesting your conditions using `if` and the AND operator `&&`

Comment: Ok, I'll play around with it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm struggling to come up with the logic to my problem. Any guidance would be appreciated. I've been able to get it to sort by year & month, the problem is, the months go the wrong way. It goes Dec14, Nov14, Oct 15, Sep 15, Aug 15, July 15, etc, etc

Comment: Edit your question with an **\[EDIT\]** tag and put what you accomplished so far there, like "\[EDIT\]: I've used `usort` with this callback function `{code bla bla}` but it returns this `{unexpected output}` when it needed to be *{explanation}*

Comment: Sorry, I did that instead.

Comment: Try sorting it only by YEAR. The month number will set itself by asc order I think. (will try to reproduce your problem)

Comment: Sorting only by year leaves the year in the correct order but the months are completely random it seems

Comment: Check out my answer, I think that's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your answer lies as an [user contribution note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php#114535) on **PHP Docs's** `uasort()` function page, by *"clement.hk"*. I've adapted it to your problem and it seems to work!

```
<?php

// array reproduction
$months = array(
        '1'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>2015),
        '2'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>2015),
        '3'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>2015),
        '4'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>2015),
        '5'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>2015),
        '6'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>2015),
        '7'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>2015),
        '8'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>2015),
        '9'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>2015),
        '10'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>2015),
        '11'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>2014),
        '12'=>array('TOTAL'=>0, 'YEAR'=>2014)
);

// "clement.hk"'s alternate version of "uasort", where it keeps
// the index order when $a == $b. Credits to him!
function stable_uasort(&$array, $cmp_function) {
    if(count($array) < 2) {
        return;
    }
    $halfway = count($array) / 2;
    $array1 = array_slice($array, 0, $halfway, TRUE);
    $array2 = array_slice($array, $halfway, NULL, TRUE);

    stable_uasort($array1, $cmp_function);
    stable_uasort($array2, $cmp_function);
    if(call_user_func($cmp_function, end($array1), reset($array2)) < 1) {
        $array = $array1 + $array2;
        return;
    }
    $array = array();
    reset($array1);
    reset($array2);
    while(current($array1) && current($array2)) {
        if(call_user_func($cmp_function, current($array1), current($array2)) < 1) {
            $array[key($array1)] = current($array1);
            next($array1);
        } else {
            $array[key($array2)] = current($array2);
            next($array2);
        }
    }
    while(current($array1)) {
        $array[key($array1)] = current($array1);
        next($array1);
    }
    while(current($array2)) {
        $array[key($array2)] = current($array2);
        next($array2);
    }
    return;
}

// the equal comparison is pointless since you have twelve months of the same
// year... we need comparison only when it differs
stable_uasort($months, function ($a, $b) {
/*     if($a['YEAR'] == $b['YEAR']) {
        return 0;
    } */
    return ($a['YEAR'] > $b['YEAR']) ? 1 : -1;
});


echo '<pre>';
print_r($months);
```

**The output:**

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [TOTAL] => 0
            [YEAR] => 2014
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [TOTAL] => 0
            [YEAR] => 2014
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [TOTAL] => 0
            [YEAR] => 2015
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [TOTAL] => 0
            [YEAR] => 2015
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [TOTAL] => 0
            [YEAR] => 2015
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [TOTAL] => 0
            [YEAR] => 2015
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [TOTAL] => 0
            [YEAR] => 2015
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [TOTAL] => 0
            [YEAR] => 2015
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [TOTAL] => 0
            [YEAR] => 2015
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [TOTAL] => 0
            [YEAR] => 2015
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [TOTAL] => 0
            [YEAR] => 2015
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [TOTAL] => 0
            [YEAR] => 2015
        )

)
```

Seems `uasort` can go unstable when issuing multi-leveled sortings while it maintains array index order when they have same values. The [talking](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53341) is that is currently fixed on PHP7 for small size arrays (<16), so if you dare it, may be worth the trying!

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and post back!

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for the help! And thanks to that person from php.net!

Answer (score 0):

you can use usort and add your logic in there with conditions. An example with sorting only by your total value would be this.

```
function sortFunction($item1, $item2)
{
    return $item1->TOTAL - $item2->TOTAL;
}

usort($months, "sortFunction");
```

Comment: usort / uasort is definitely going to be the solution. I am struggling to come up with the logic to achieve the result, however. I can get it to sort by the year & month, but the months are going to wrong way.  It goes Dec14, Nov14, Oct15, Sept15, etc etc.